# How can I construct coordinate axes where the origin has a single label?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, d3.js, coordinate-systems

I wish to plot polynomial functions with d3.js and **I am looking for the right solution**(which should be simpler than constructing the axes from scratch) on **how to construct coordinate axes** in 2D where I have a **single label for the origin**.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here - please provide some more details on the specifics of what you are trying to accomplish, along with anything you have tried so far.  The API documentation for [d3.scale.linear](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear) seems like a good starting point

Comment: the question is: how to construct coordinate axes in 2D where I have a single label for the origin? I'm able to construct 2 axes, but then the 0 label is duplicated, and looks really ugly. I can emulate the axes with custom lines and text, or I can think about similarly ugly constructs. I am looking for the solutions which is easy and nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 axes can be manipulated after they are generated.  For instance, you can remove the origin labels by selecting them specifically:

```
//make default origin labels invisible
svg.selectAll(".axis g text")
    .filter(function(d) {return d==0 ? true : false})
    .style("opacity", 1e-6);
```

you can then add your own origin label:

```
//add a custom origin identifier
svg.append("text")
    .attr({
        "class": "origintext",
        "x": -8,
        "y": height + 8,
        "text-anchor": "end",
        "dy": ".71em"
    })
    .text("(0,0)");
```

see full implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/kcPEX/1/

[image: Single origin label]

Comment: May I ask why the opacity hast to be 1e-6? seems strange.

Comment: in 'return d==0 ? true : false', why bother with the ternary operation and not just: 'return d==0;' ?